# Resource Monitor not showing expected disk read activity

Tags: perfmon

Hi I have the following query.

I am running a meteor web server on a windows 2008 R2 VM machine.

Am trying to run a performance test on the web server. 
I have an automated script to access a folder on the server via the web gui, then download a 2GB file repeatedly.
The 2GB file is located on the local disk of the VM machine. [D:]

I am encountering the following situation

- While running the performance monitor to monitor disk read/sec and disk read B/s, for the duration of the test, there was no noticeable disk read activity.
- During the duration of the test, I am also looking at Resource Monitor to monitor processes with disk activity, and there is also no noticeable disk read activities. (though there are a lot of disk write activities)

To check that the Performance Monitor and Resource monitor are running properly, I have also done a test to repeatedly upload files to the server, and these have shown the expected disk write activities.

I initially suspected that the file might be cached by a proxy server along the way, so I have added steps in the testing script to repeatedly rename the file on the VM machine before attempting to download it via the web gui. Monitoring the resource monitor while this is going on, I still do not see any disk read activities, this is puzzling.

Appreciate if anyone could point out where I'm going wrong, or if I'm not looking for the disk read activities in the right places.

The web application is set up to zip the file before sending it to the end user. As such, in order to zip the file, there should be some sort of read activity to read the file before zipping it. It is a 2GB text file, and takes considerable time to zip, but on the resource monitor, I do not see any processes that seem to be doing disk reads while the zipping is ongoing. We are using 7zip for zipping.